# Android TextEdit expands past screen edge when populated by a large number

Tags: android, tablelayout, stretch, textedit

I have several text edits in a table layout. With small values, the TextEdits stretch to the edge of the screen.  However, large values cause the TextEdits to expand past the screen edge.  How do I keep the textedit width to the screen edge at all times?

```
    <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow android:baselineAligned="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Perm:" style="@style/PlainText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/f" android:hint="0" android:scrollHorizontally="true"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/PlainText" android:id="@+id/textView5" android:text="w/ repetition:" android:gravity="right"></TextView>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/e" android:hint="0" android:scrollHorizontally="true"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Combinations:" style="@style/PlainText"></TextView>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/d" android:hint="0" android:scrollHorizontally="true"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/PlainText" android:id="@+id/textView6" android:text="w/ repetition:" android:gravity="right"></TextView>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/c" android:hint="0" android:scrollHorizontally="true"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="# of subsets:" style="@style/PlainText"></TextView>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/b" android:hint="0" android:scrollHorizontally="true"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Pigeonhole:" style="@style/PlainText"></TextView>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/z" android:hint="0" android:scrollHorizontally="true"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this can restrict the no of letters user input into the edit text.

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

this will restrict the over flow of characters.

i noticed some are numeric fields. so using

```
android:inputType="number"
```

or any other matching option.

**UPDATE**

something like this will stretch the selected column to take up the remaining space

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Open..."
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-O"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

check this link for more info

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Comment: I've thought of that idea but I actually would prefer that it always goes to the edge of the screen regardless of screen size or orientation. Input type is not a big deal, preferably I'd rather them just be able to copy but not actually input values into this edit text, but that's not a big deal/nor the point.

Comment: Basically, I have an EditText that I want to resize to fit content but NOT go past the edge of the screen. So basically in landscape or in portrait it would either get larger as required until it hits the edge of the screen and then stops and just lets you scroll through the text instead of growing. Alternatively, I'm also okay with it always being the length of the remaining space on the screen regardless of orientation.

Comment: for your first option you have to register a OnTextChangedListener and change the length of edit text based on number of characters entered by user. for second option you can used layout_Width='dip'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the second option is the better way to go to be honest. I tried your suggestion. when I set Layout width to 'dip' it returns "You must supply a layout_width attribute." in the graphical layout as in it's not reading it as a proper value.

Comment: i guess i was too abstract for you that ment **android:layout_width="100dip"** where 100 is a hard coded value. it depends on your layout.

Comment: Oh I should have figured. Thought it might have been some universal size if you just put it to dip it would automatically use the entire depth (like a default). Anyways, the problem with that is that it won't reach the edge of the screen for all devices in both orientations. I'd rather it always use the entire remaining space in the table row. I thought fill parent would do that. Apparently not.

Comment: @akand074: check my updated answer. if you want the text-view to stretch and take the remaining space.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I want to do. It's really late here I'll give it a try and let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: That didn't have exactly what I needed because that stretches the first column which pushes the other to the right side. But it did lead me to what I needed. There was actually a "shrink column" that I wasn't even aware of surprisingly. Anyways setting them to both shrink and stretch fixed the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer ended up being android:shrinkColumns(#, #) rather than hard coding the size. comment from @akand074 in the answer comments.  I found this link which explains why and how this works:

http://growingupwithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-does-tablelayout-handle-column.html#remindMeAgain